# how to make sprite fall straight down in unity2d (and not move from its column)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

How can I make sprites fall straight down, and resist any sideways motion whether by dragging or physics?

My code instantiates a prefab at runtime which has an attached script.

The script runs the following function after a while:

```
void addSliderJoint() {
    myVerticalSlider = gameObject.AddComponent<SliderJoint2D> () as SliderJoint2D;
    myVerticalSlider.angle = 90;
}
```

After this functions runs, I'd like the sprites to only move vertically, but they seem happy to move without restriction.  I can "see" the SliderJoint2D in the inspector during runtime, and if I change its settings in the GUI, the sprites suddenly respond to it.

Sample repo available at https://github.com/thunderrabbit/finna-be-octo-wallhack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this to your OnMouseDrag() method

```
// Set the Position
    Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(startPos.x, startPos.y + dir.y);
    transform.position = newPos;
```

Comment: I don't want them to be fixed from the outset, but I can work with this.  Thanks for such a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, If you'd like an object to move only according to one axis, you could add a **Rigidbody** (not Rigidbody2D), and set the Constraints on the object to freeze the positions besides the axis you want to translate it on.

Comment: Would the Rigidbody2D be replaced at runtime or should I use a Rigidbody from the outset?

Comment: I tried this, but it overly complicates other things, first of all, I'd have to use 3D colliders instead of 2D.  If I go this route, I think I'd convert the entire project to 3D.

Comment: Well I had a similar problem of some sort, and I switched only the object I needed to 3D, but yeah this is probably not the best way to deal with it, glad you solved your problem!